# Owl carousel not showing images despite height given

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I have the following code snippet from my template whre I've used owl carousel jquery library for slider.

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  lazyLoad: false,
  loop: true
});
```

```css
.owl-carousel .owl-lazy {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<section class="slider-wrapper">
  <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature"></div>
    <div class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?food"></div>
    <div class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?travel"></div>
    <div class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?work"></div>
    <div class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?pet"></div>
    <div class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?music"></div>
    <div class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?friends"></div>
    <div class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?movie"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I'm looking forward to create a full height and width carousel. Although I have given the height to the image container `owl-lazy` the images are not visible. The above code only dot navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution if you want to implement it as a background-image instead of a `<img>` Tag.

I Just set `lazyLoad: true` and defined a `min-height` on the `background-image` Container.

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  lazyLoad: true,
  loop: true
});
```

```css
.owl-carousel .owl-lazy {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<section class="slider-wrapper">
  <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature"></div>
    <div class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?food"></div>
    <div class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?travel"></div>
    <div class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?work"></div>
    <div class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?pet"></div>
    <div class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?music"></div>
    <div class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?friends"></div>
    <div class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?movie"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the best to use `div` or `img` tag ?

Comment: Depends on what you need. If you want it as a Intro Header with some text displaying on top I would use the `background-image` variant. If it's  just for displaying pictures which are not necessarily full height and/or full width I would go with `<img>` Tags...